# Meta-lambda symbol (Higher-order symbol)

Tags: symbols

[Bart Jacobs](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/), in his book [*Categorical Logic and Type Theory*](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/CLT/bookinfo.html), uses a very cool notation for "meta-lambda abstraction":

[image: lambda double bar]

In context, it looks like this:
[image: lambda lambda, two lambda superposed]

It sorts of remind of the [haskell logo](https://www.haskell.org/static/img/haskell-logo.svg?etag=ukf3Fg7-), but it looks like this symbol does not exists (I checked the usual resources, listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/34551)).

Did anyone ever meet this symbol?
Any suggestion on how to typeset it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just two lambdas with raising and overlapping.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\metalambda}{%
  \mathop{%
    \rlap{$\lambda$}%
    \mkern2mu
    \raisebox{.275ex}{$\lambda$}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\metalambda x\mathpunct{.}f(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The parameters might need adjusting for different fonts.

Answer (score 6):

Works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip,scalerel}
\def\metalambda{\mathop{\scalerel*{\stackengine{1.9pt}{$\lambda$}{%
  \kern3.4pt\smash{\clipbox{2pt -.5pt 0pt -.5pt}{$\lambda$}}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}{X}\mkern1mu}}
\begin{document}
$\lambda x:\sigma.M\quad \metalambda x.f(x)$\par
$\scriptstyle\lambda x:\sigma.M\quad \metalambda x.f(x)$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\lambda x:\sigma.M\quad \metalambda x.f(x)$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your convincing and portable answer, but egreg's answer's simplicity in terms of package make his answer more easy to use.